# Byte Buddy installOn API giving error: adding retransformable transformers is not supported?

Tags: java, spring-boot, bytecode, byte-buddy

Why installOn API is giving an error in my code. I want to call instrumentation.retransformClasses API from another thread. 
or can we call instrumentation.retransformClasses API in bytebuddy.
I want to insert a static field after class is loaded. If that's possible, a short example would be great!

```
public static void premain(String arguments, Instrumentation instrumentation) {

    System.out.println("Agent for add fields ");
    final ByteBuddy byteBuddy = new ByteBuddy().with(Implementation.Context.Disabled.Factory.INSTANCE);
    new AgentBuilder.Default()    
              .with(byteBuddy).with(RedefinitionStrategy.RETRANSFORMATION)
              .with(new AgentBuilder.InitializationStrategy.SelfInjection.Eager())
              .with(TypeStrategy.Default.REDEFINE)
              .type((ElementMatchers.nameContains("Method")))
              .transform(new Transformer() {
                   public Builder<?> transform(Builder<?> arg0, TypeDescription arg1, ClassLoader arg2,
                            JavaModule arg3) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        return null;
                    }
                })
              .installOn(instrumentation);

    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Thread Running");
            try {
                Thread.currentThread().sleep(10000);

                Class c[] = instrumentation.getAllLoadedClasses();
                for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
                    String clsName = c[i].getName();

                    System.out.println(clsName);
                    if (clsName.equals("com.github.shehanperera.example.Method")) {

                            instrumentation.retransformClasses(c[i]);
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println(e);
            }

        }
    };

    thread.start(); 
}
```

Giving exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:386)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(InstrumentationImpl.java:401)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not install class file transformer
    at net.bytebuddy.agent.builder.AgentBuilder$Default.installOn(AgentBuilder.java:8538)
    at net.bytebuddy.agent.builder.AgentBuilder$Default$Delegator.installOn(AgentBuilder.java:10179)
    at com.github.shehanperera.addfield.Agent.premain(Agent.java:39)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: adding retransformable transformers is not supported in this environment
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.addTransformer(InstrumentationImpl.java:88)
    at net.bytebuddy.agent.builder.AgentBuilder$Default.installOn(AgentBuilder.java:8514)
    ... 8 more
FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed
```

Comment: Adding retransformable transformers only works when a JavaAgent requesting this capability has been specified at JVM start time. But you can't add fields when retransforming anyway. At least, [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.instrument/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html#retransformClasses(java.lang.Class...)) says: *The retransformation must not add, remove or rename fields or methods, change the signatures of methods, or change inheritance.* You need load time transformation when you want to add fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javassist does not allow anything like that by default, javassist just does simple clever trick and allows you to edit class before it's actually loaded, as classes are loaded on first use. Otherwise typical agent with retransform must be used too.

And to create instrumentation that can retransform classes you must add proper flag to manifest:
    Can-Retransform-Classes: true

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html

Comment: can you please explain in above code why installOn API giving error .

Comment: what are you using to get the Instrumentation instance itself? Do you created this as separate agent .jar? or using some other special library?

Comment: Yes, I created separate agent.jar

Comment: then just like I said, your agent.jar should have manifest file, like here: https://www.baeldung.com/java-instrumentation#create-agent-manifest-file

Comment: thanks, for pointing out I am missing that and after some changes in the code this problem is resolved, but I think for now it is fact you can not add the field into class after it is loaded.